# Plotting independent data sets of different size in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to read 3 independent data sets each of which having a different size and plot them using a boxplot, e.g.:

```
Set1 Set2 Set3
1    1    1
1    2    2
1    2    2
     3    3
     3    3
          4
```

(As string: `"Set1 Set2 Set3\n1    1    1\n1    2    2\n1    2    2\n     3    3\n     3    3\n          4\n"`)

However, the column width could vary, e.g. when a value has more than 5 digits.

When I do `results = read.table("data.dat", header=TRUE)` RStudio will report:

```
line 4 did not have 3 elements
```

Using the option `fill=TRUE` would shift every field in line 4 to the left and fill the empty field ont the right with a `NA` which directly biases the data.

Because of the fact that the column size may vary, I tried to load it as a CSV file but this had the effect that the median for `Set1` became `NA`.

Same data as CSV:

```
Set1,Set2,Set3
1,1,1
1,2,2
1,2,2
,3,3
,3,3
,,4
```

So how can I plot all sets in a single diagram without the data being changed by R?

**EDIT1:** Gave more details for the used data format. Also I emphasize that the column size might vary and not be as fixed in the example

Comment: Try `median(..., na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: First read as you did setting `fill = TRUE` and then use `boxplot(df, na.omit = TRUE)`

Comment: @konvas: worked, thx...@DatamineR: this did not make any difference in the plot :-/ @both: I still have the problem that `fill=TRUE` shifts the values to the left and then fills up the rest with `NA`s (when I don't read a csv) .

Comment: Can you do a `dput(readChar("data.dat"), nchars = 100)` and paste the results here? We can then formulate the best way to read in your file.

Comment: I would, but I get an error: `Error in dput(readChar("data.dat"), nchars = 100) : 
  unused argument (nchars = 100)`

Comment: Oops should be: `dput(readChar("data.dat", nchars = 100))`

Comment: `boxplot(read.csv("data.csv"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75216/discussion-between-paddre-and-vlo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads the indicated file with the indicated field widths.  The first (header line) is skipped and the indicated column names are used.  Empty fields (`na.strings=""`) are regarded as `NA`:

```
results <- read.fwf("data.dat", widths = c(5L, 5L, 5L), skip = 1, 
  na.strings = "", col.names = c("Set1", "Set2", "Set3"))

boxplot(results)
```

(continued after image)

[image]

**Note:** One cannot tell the exact content of data.dat from the question and that could be crucial but for purposes of this answer we have assumed this:

```
Lines <- c("Set1 Set2 Set3", 
           "1    1    1", 
           "1    2    2", 
           "1    2    2", 
           "     3    3", 
           "     3    3", 
           "          4")
writeLines(Lines, "data.dat")
```

Comment: The assumption was correct ;-) Will add it to the question. It works for me, but could you pls give some explanation on the `read.fwf(...)` line? In particular: why does it work and how?

Comment: Also (as you can see in the updated queation), I want to emphasize that I cannot be bound to a fixed column size. So a solution regarding CSVs might probably be more helpful

Comment: Have added some additional commentary. Note that if the column size is not fixed in the original version of the question then the input is ambiguous since you can't tell which column a number is in.  Is the 4 in the last line in the last column? the first column?  If you have csv input as the revised version then use `read.csv("data.dat")`